# SQL Select Only the Most Common Results

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have a table with IDs and Items where sometimes the associated Item has a variation from the other Items associated with the same ID.  I need a query that selects the most common Item and assigns it to that ID.

The below query works, but I'm hoping to optimize it to avoid having to join two separate CTEs at the end, and rather have one slick SELECT statement:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Test') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Test

CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    [ID] INT
    ,[Item] VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT #Test
VALUES
(100, 'Apple'),
(100, 'Apple'),
(100, 'Apples'),
(200, 'Orange'),
(200, 'Orange'),
(200, 'Orange'),
(200, 'Oranges'),
(300, 'Grape');

WITH cteOne AS (SELECT
[ID]
,[Item]
,COUNT(*) [Count]
FROM #Test
GROUP BY [ID]
,[Item]
),
cteTwo AS (SELECT
[ID]
,MAX([Count]) [Max]
FROM cteOne
GROUP BY [ID])

SELECT
C1.[ID]
,C1.[Item]
FROM cteOne C1
INNER JOIN cteTwo C2 ON C2.[ID] = C1.[ID]
AND C2.[Max] = C1.[Count]
ORDER BY [ID]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `top 1 with ties` with `row_number`

```
select
    top 1 with ties [ID], [Item]
from (
    SELECT
        [ID], [Item], COUNT(*) [Count]
    FROM #Test
    GROUP BY [ID], [Item]
) t
order by row_number() over (partition by [ID] order by [Count] desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is even better:

```
;WITH 
cteOne AS (
    SELECT [ID],[Item] ,COUNT(*) [Count]
    FROM #Test
    GROUP BY [ID],[Item]
),
cteTwoo as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by count) idx
    from cteOne
)
select ID, Item
from cteTwoo
where idx = 1
```

Comment: CTE_Three is not created.